# What does a magic packet look like?

Tags: tcpip, ethernet, wake-on-lan

What does a magic packet contain and what options does the protocol provide?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Wikipedia Entry on [Wake on LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_on_lan)

> The Magic Packet is a broadcast frame
>   containing anywhere within its payload
>   6 bytes of ones (resulting in
>   hexadecimal FF FF FF FF FF FF)
>   followed by sixteen repetitions of the
>   target computer's MAC address.